# How the shell constructs a string by looping

Tags: bash, shell, printf, double-quotes

I need to construct redis dummy data, and when constructing redis `hash` data, I want to construct hash data for `a large number of fields` through a for loop.

I call the printf construct directly to achieve the desired result, but when stored in a variable, the result is not as expected, the sample code is as follows

```bash
#!/bin/bash
for no in $(seq 5); do
    printf "%s%s %s " "$data" "filed$no" "val$no"
done
# stdout: 
# bash test.sh
filed1 val1 filed2 val2 filed3 val3 filed4 val4 filed5 val5
```

save to variable

```bash
#!/bin/bash
data=""
for no in $(seq 5); do
    data="$(printf "%s%s %s " "$data" "filed$no" "val$no")"
done
printf "%s\n" $data

# stdout
# bash test.sh 
filed1
val1
filed2
val2
filed3
val3
filed4
val4
filed5
val5
```

This seems to be escaping spaces into line breaks, how can I solve it? I really appreciate any help with this.

Comment: As an aside, the command substitution is unnecessary and inefficient; try `printf -v data "%sfiled%s val%s " "$data" "$no" "$no"`

Comment: Or just `data+="filed$no val$no "`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote the variable:

```
printf "%s\n" "$data"
```

When not quoted, `$data` is expanded into several arguments. `printf` reuses the format specifier repeatedly for all of its arguments.

See [printf](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#SHELL_BUILTIN_COMMANDS):

> **The format is reused as necessary to consume all of the
> arguments**.  If the format requires more arguments than are
> supplied, the extra format specifications behave as if a
> zero value or null string, as appropriate, had been
> supplied.  The return value is zero on success, non-zero
> on failure.

A simple demonstration:

```
$ printf "hello %s\n" a b c
hello a
hello b
hello c
$ printf "hello %s\n" "a b c"
hello a b c
$
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will pay attention to this kind of silly mistake.

Comment: The general suggestion is to always *quote* variables unless you have specific reasons.